# Mocking Volley Network to simulate a network error

Tags: android, mocking, mockito, robolectric, android-volley

:)

I'm facing an issue simulating network exceptions using Volley. My idea is to "mock" a Network class that will always throw an exception. Then use that Network in my RequestQueue and test how my DataManager(MyManager) behaves when a network exception is thrown. I know the approach may not be fully correct, but then I wish I could knew a better way to implement my UnitTest case.

By the way, I use Robolectric 2.2 and Mockito 1.9.5. Let's dig into the code:

```
RequestQueue mMainRequestQueue;
private Network mMockedNetwork;

@Before
public void setup(){
    Robolectric.getFakeHttpLayer().interceptHttpRequests(false);

    ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
    mMockedNetwork = spy(new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack()));
    mMainRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(new NoCache(), mMockedNetwork);
    mMainRequestQueue.start();
}

@Test
public void testLogin() throws Exception {

    doThrow(new VolleyError()).when(mMockedNetwork).performRequest(any(JsonObjectRequest.class));

    MyManager.getInstance(Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext()).setMainQueue(mMainRequestQueue);
    MyManager.getInstance(Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext()).createSession("sessionId", "date", new MyManager.OnResponseReceivedListener() {
        @Override
        public void responseReceived(boolean error, Object responseObject) {
            if (error) {
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    });

}
```

MyManager `createSession(..)` method just creates a new instance of a `JsonObjectRequest` and invokes `OnResponseReceivedListener`'s method whenever a response is received.

When I run the test, the callback methods (the ones in JSONObjectRequest and of course the one in the listener) are never called.

Any idea why? Am I missing something? Maybe the whole approach is wrong?

Thanks a lot people!

## EDIT

I've also tried replacing `new RequestQueue(...)` line with this one `mMainRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(new NoCache(), mMockedNetwork, 4,new ExecutorDelivery(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()));`

Same result.

## EDIT 2

As David Wallace has mentioned, that method is called from a Volley library class Called NetworkDispatcher [Here is the link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/NetworkDispatcher.java)

```
....
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag(request.getTrafficStatsTag());
            }

            // Perform the network request.
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = mNetwork.performRequest(request);
            request.addMarker("network-http-complete");

            // If the server returned 304 AND we delivered a response already,
            // we're done -- don't deliver a second identical response.
            if (networkResponse.notModified && request.hasHadResponseDelivered()) {
                request.finish("not-modified");
                continue;
            }
...
```

The networkDispatchers are created within the RequestQueue, using the "mocked" object as parameter. So I expect that method to be called.

Comment: Can you show the code that actually calls `performRequest`?

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks for getting involve David. performRequest is called from within Volley Library. Thanks god is Open Source. I will paste the code. Please check the Edit :)

Comment: So, that call is in the `run` method of the class you pasted.  Where in your test are you calling this from?  I'm not sure why you are expecting your callbacks to be called, when I can't see anything that calls them.

Comment: @DavidWallace Sorry David, I deleted an important line while copying the code from my project. You are probably missing `mMainRequestQueue.start();` call in the `@Before` method. That method creates 4 NetworkDispatchers (Threads) and call their `start()`, so the `run()` is called right afterwards. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Well there's your problem.  I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer to your question? I am also trying to use Mockito to test my Volley API Requests, but currently I can't find a solution to my problem. What I want to do is something I described in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857835/is-there-another-android-unit-testing-framework-i-could-use-aside-from-robolectr. So basically I want to catch, or from what I have learned-mock, the api calls done on my oncreate method in original app and edit or set a response when it returns a success code. Do you have any ideas how I can pull it off?

Comment: Hi @JohnErnestGuadalupe. Sorry to say that I couldn't find a solution for this. So I stick to the definition of UnitTesting, and forget about testing the behavior of Volley. Instedd, I just test how my app reacts to it...Anyway, I would like to see this solved, but it really seems to be super complex...

Answer (score 1):

In your `@Before` method, you start the `RequestQueue` thread, which in turn calls `performRequest`.  Later, in your `@Test` method, you stub the `performRequest` method - that is, you specify what should happen when `performRequest` is called.

But this creates a race condition.  The behaviour of this test is indeterminate, because we can't tell whether the `RequestQueue` thread will reach the call to `performRequest` before or after that call is stubbed.  So you might get the original version of the method, or you might get the stubbed version.  The only way to be sure is to re-engineer the way the test works.

You really need to stub `performRequest` FIRST, and then start your `RequestQueue` thread.  Probably the simplest thing to do would be to move `mMainRequestQueue.start();` down into the `@Test` method, after all the stubbing has been done.

Comment: Thanks David. I've tried what you say (moving the start() method into test properly, but it doesn't work. I'm starting to think that the issue is more on Robolectric or Volley side. Mockito works fine alone anyway...